# API best practice to of usage Methods types

Tags: c#, api, web

Is it correct to use the **POST** method for all API routes in the Controller?

Comment: No, no it is not but that depends on what you mean by "all API routes".

Comment: Nobody's stopping you from using DELTEE or GET for everything either, your users may get surprises if you do.

Comment: No its not, take a look here https://restfulapi.net/http-methods/

Comment: It seems that your question opinion based. Check community rules for more clear questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your requirements . First try to read about all the HTTP verbs from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods.
Then based on your need , use the related http verb.